# How do I remove an element from a list and not let it come back even if declared again?

Tags: python, arrays, list

so I'm trying to create guess the number game with python with unique hints, so after every guess there will be a random hint out of 3.

One of the hints can't be shown more than one time. so I tried removing it from the array of hints, but the problem is that everytime I call the function it's declared back to the list of hints.

```
def chosen_hint(guess):
    hints = [bigger_lower(guess), even_uneven(), close_far(guess)]
    hint = random.choice(hints)
    if hint == even_uneven():
        hints.remove(even_uneven())
    return hint
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage the list *outside* the function. You can pass the list of valid hints as an argument, and return both the chosen hint and the list of remaining hints, or you can define a class that manages the list of available hints.

```
import random


class HintSet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hint_makers = [bigger_lower, even_uneven, close_far]

    def get_hint(self, guess):
        hint_maker = random.choice(self.hint_makers)
        if hint_maker is even_uneven:
            self.hint_maker.remove(hint)
        return hint_maker(guess)

hs = HintSet()

guess = ...
hint = hs.get_hint(guess)
```

Here, since the actual hint varies with the guess, we store the functions that produce hints from a guess, not the hints themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the logic game needs that this declaration happens just once and outside, ex. at the start of the game.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the list outside of the function. Then it will not declare it everytime the function is invoked. You can set the list as global inside the function if you want to do further operations on the list.

[image: Sample code]

Comment: You should not post pictures of the code. It takes effort in copying and pasting the code